# Returning a variable from second python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

i have two files, one thats called game.py, and a second one called menu.py. I need to get game. py to return a value from Menu_Screen() in menu.py

```py
#game.py
import menu
import turtle
Single_Multi = 0

def SinglePlayer():
  #do stuff

def MultiPlayer():
  #do stuff
if __name__ == "__main__"

  Single_Multi = int(menu.Menu_Screen())

  if Single_Multi == 1:
    SinglePlayer()

  elif Single_Multi == 3:
    MultiPlayer()
```

```py
#menu.py
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.cv._rootwindow.resizable(False, False)
wn.title("Pong")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)

Single_Multi = 0


class Button(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, s, text, x, y, w, h, c, i, p, a=None, b2=None, b3=None):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.msg = text
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.pensize = p
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.colour = c
        self.action = a
        self.screen = s
        self.i_color = i
        self.button2 = b2
        self.button3 = b3
        self.screen.tracer(0)
        self.ht()
        self.color(self.colour)
        self.penup()
        self.begin_fill()
        self.goto(self.x, self.y)
        self.pendown()
        self.goto(self.x + self.width, self.y)
        self.goto(self.x + self.width, self.y + self.height)
        self.goto(self.x, self.y + self.height)
        self.goto(self.x, self.y)
        self.end_fill()
        self.penup()
        self.goto(self.x + self.width / 2, self.y + self.height / 3.5)
        self.color("black")
        self.write(self.msg, False, align="center", font=("Arial", self.pensize, "bold"))
        self.screen.update()

    def check(self, f, b):
        if f < self.x + self.width and f > self.x and b > self.y and b < self.y + self.height and self.action != None:
            turtle.listen()
            turtle.onscreenclick(None, 1)
            self.color(self.colour, self.i_color)
            self.begin_fill()
            self.goto(self.x, self.y)
            self.pendown()
            self.goto(self.x + self.width, self.y)
            self.goto(self.x + self.width, self.y + self.height)
            self.goto(self.x, self.y + self.height)
            self.goto(self.x, self.y)
            self.end_fill()
            self.penup()
            self.goto(self.x + self.width / 2, self.y + self.height / 3.5)
            self.color("black")
            self.write(self.msg, False, align="center", font=("Arial", self.pensize, "bold"))
            self.screen.update()
            self.clear()
            self.action()
        elif self.button2 != None:
            self.button2.check(f, b)
            if self.button3 != None:
                self.button3.check(f, b)


def Multi_Player():
    global Single_Multi
    Single_Multi = 3


def Single_Player():
    global Single_Multi
    Single_Multi = 1

def Menu_Screen():
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.clear()
    turtle.tracer(0)
    pen = turtle.Turtle()
    wn.bgcolor("black")
    pen.ht()
    pen.penup()
    pen.clear()
    button = Button(wn, "Single_Player", -95, 50, 150, 50, "white", "#8470ff", 15, Single_Player)
    button.intro = True
    button2 = Button(wn, "Multi_Player", -95, -10, 150, 50, "white", "#8470ff", 15, Multi_Player)
    button3 = Button(wn, "Exit", -95, -70, 150, 50, "white", "grey", 15, quit, button, button2)
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(0, 100)
    pen.color("red")
    pen.write("Pong", False, align="center", font=("Arial", 90, "bold"))
    turtle.listen()
    turtle.onscreenclick(button3.check, 1)
    turtle.update()
    
    return Single_Multi
    


Menu_Screen()
wn.mainloop()
```

I can't get the mainloop in `menu.py` to end and return `Single_Multi` to `game.py` as when i run it it will run the menu and then freeze when i press a button (except for exit, that works fine).

this contains the complete menu.py file so there isn't any confusion

if you need me  to add more of the code, let me know, this has been stumping me for a day and a half

Comment: can you provide information on what type of error do you get, and what does wn.winloop() do/ it's code?

Comment: it freezes when i press a menu button and then when i hit X to exit it throws this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 4, in <module>
    import menu
  File "/home/alucard/other_python/Pygame/Space-invaders/Space-Invaders-Application-master/extra/menu.py", line 113, in <module>
    wn.clear()

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 1019, in clear
    self._delete("all")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 557, in _delete
    self.cv.delete(item)
  File "<string>", line 1, in delete
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2818, in delete
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'delete') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"

Comment: "window.mainloop() tells Python to run the Tkinter event loop. This method listens for events, such as button clicks or keypresses, and blocks any code that comes after it from running until the window it’s called on is closed. "

Comment: first of all, your game.py file, has incorrect equality operator usage, it's supposed to be if Single_Multi == 1: and vice versa.

Comment: I cannot understand how your code even functions, where does the wn.mainloop come from, when have you ever assigned wn as something in the global scope.

Comment: my bad, ill edit my answer to fix that

Comment: hmm, so what i understood from your program is that the Menu_Screen() Function is not needed, since you are importing a function that returns something from another python file, so why do you need this at the end, if all you're gonna do is use this function.

Comment: you're asking why i don't just put it all in the same file?

Comment: You should probably add `if __name__ == "__main__":` to the menu.py to run the other part of the code, when you call the function.

Comment: i'm still confused why do you need to call the Menu_Screen function in the menu.py file.

Comment: someone sent some code to me to make work and i was just trying to help them, the Menu_Screen() is for a game menu that allows the user to select whether they want to play multiplayer or singleplayer, i was just trying to take advantage of code that was already written by them, it sends it back to the main game file

Comment: Try moving the call to wn.mainloop() to the end of the game.py file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my question so I'll post this answer in case it can help someone in the future

```py
def Menu_Screen():
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.clear()
    turtle.tracer(0)
    pen = turtle.Turtle()
    wn.bgcolor("black")
    pen.ht()
    pen.penup()
    pen.clear()
    button = Button(wn, "Single_Player", -95, 50, 150, 50, "white", "#8470ff", 15, Single_Player)
    button.intro = True
    button2 = Button(wn, "Multi_Player", -95, -10, 150, 50, "white", "#8470ff", 15, Multi_Player)
    button3 = Button(wn, "Exit", -95, -70, 150, 50, "white", "grey", 15, quit, button, button2)
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(0, 100)
    pen.color("red")
    pen.write("Pong", False, align="center", font=("Arial", 90, "bold"))
    while 1 == 1:
        turtle.listen()
        turtle.onscreenclick(button3.check, 1)
        turtle.update()
        if Single_Multi != 0:
            break;


    wn.clear()
    return Single_Multi
    


    Menu_Screen()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    wn.mainloop()
```

I just added an infinite while loop inside of the Menu_Screen() function and got the wn.mainloop() under `if __name__ == "__main__":`